# How to indicate in postgreSQL command in which database to execute a script? (simmilar to SQL Server "use" command)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following problem, I need to put in a script that is going to run before the new version is rolled the SQL code that enables the pgAgent in PostgreSQL. However, this code should be run on the maintenance database (postgres) and the database where we run the script file is another one.

I remember that in SQL Server there is a command "use " so you could do something like:

```
use foo

-- some code

use bar 

-- more code
```

is there something similar in PostgreSQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to switch databases in psql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949876/how-to-switch-databases-in-psql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well after looking on the web for some time I found this which was what I need it
http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html

Answer (score 17):

You can put in your file something like:

```
\c first_db_name
select * from t; --- your sql
\c second_db_name
select * from t; --- your sql
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you piping these commands through the `psql` command? If so, `\c databasename` is what you want.

[psql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/app-psql.html)

Comment: Actually the input is a text file that is processed by the database

Comment: How it's "processed  by the database"? You have to use *some* Postgres client to connect to it. Which one?

Comment: It's a client that executes the text file and it connects to the database through the ODBC driver. To make it easier imagine I'm on the pgAdmin client and I want to run a script that will make an update in two different databases.

Comment: JDBC dont recognize `\c` so I have to connect to specific jdbc URL that I want to connect. And execute SQL file.

Comment: If you're using JDBC, then you are not using psql. `\c` is not SQL - it's a psql command. Postgres database connections can't be switched to a different database on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

You can't switch databases in Postgres in this way. You actually have to reconnect to the other database.

Comment: and is there a way to do this from the script or do I have to do it from the application that is connecting to the database?

Comment: From the application. If you are done with the first db connection, just drop it, otherwise you'll need to make two connections. I had asked the pg developers the same question a while back. I don't recall their reasons for doing so. But they said that even though pgadmin and psql appear to be just switching databases, they are really establishing a new connection.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't have the USE command.  You would most likely use psql with the --dbname option to accomplish this, --dbname takes the database name as a parameter.  See this link for details on the other options you can pass in you will also want to check out the --file option as well.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/app-psql.html