# How to switch databases in psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

In MySQL, I used `use database_name;`

What's the `psql` equivalent?

Comment: OK, so this is about `psql`, the front-end for PostgreSQL?

Comment: A MySQL "database" is in fact a schema. Therefor in most cases, MySQL's "databases" would better be mapped to schemas in Postgres anyway. And if that is done, you can change the current schema using `set schema 'schema_name';` or `set search_path to schema_name;`

Comment: schemas are generally under databases.

Answer (score 2286, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, you can use the [`\connect`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) meta-command of the client tool psql:

```
\connect DBNAME
```

or in short:

```
\c DBNAME
```

Comment: +1:  This is JUST a psql command, in Postgres itself, there is no way to "switch".  In fact,  psql isn't "switching" in the MySQL context, just closing one connection and opening another.

Comment: So there is no chance to do it with SQL?

Comment: So can this work among SQL statements in a `.sql` file? e.g. can I have `CREATE DATABASE mydb;` followed by `\connect mydb`?

Comment: @Ciwan I'm pretty sure you can't include `psql` commands in a SQL script file.

Comment: For "switching" schema, use [`set searchpath=schema_name`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH).

Comment: @HansGinzel that changes schema not database there is a huge difference!

Comment: @Peter: MySQL's databases are in fact schemas. So in most cases they should be mapped to a schema in Postgres, rather than a database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name while that might be true for mysql its not for postgres.

Comment: @Peter: I know that. However the question is about the MySQL equivalent of switching "a database".

Comment: to connect with username and password `\connect mydb myusername;`

Comment: @J86 Yes, you can use a `CREATE DATABASE mydb;` line followed by a `\connect mydb` line in a `.sql` file, so long as that file is being run by `psql`. (eg. using psql to run: `\i path_to_sql_script.sql`) [I know because I just tried this and it works]

Answer (score 199):

You can connect to a database with `\c <database>` or `\connect <database>`.

Answer (score 109):

At the PSQL prompt, you can do:

```
\connect (or \c) dbname
```

Answer (score 47):

use `\c databaseName` or `\connect databaseName`

(Working on psql 13.3)

Comment: This is pretty much a copy of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 39):

You can select the database when connecting with psql. This is handy when using it from a script:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE SCHEMA test AUTHORIZATION test;" test
```

Answer (score 21):

Though not explicitly stated in the question, the purpose is to connect to a specific schema/database.

Another option is to directly connect to the schema. Example:

`sudo -u postgres psql -d my_database_name`

Source from `man psql`:

```
-d dbname
--dbname=dbname
   Specifies the name of the database to connect to. This is equivalent to specifying dbname as the first non-option argument on the command line.

   If this parameter contains an = sign or starts with a valid URI prefix (postgresql:// or postgres://), it is treated as a conninfo string. See Section 31.1.1, “Connection Strings”, in the
   documentation for more information.
```

Answer (score 18):

`\l` for databases
`\c` DatabaseName to switch to db
`\df` for procedures stored in particular database

Answer (score 14):

Using psql's meta-command  `\c or \connect [ dbname [ username ] [ host ] [ port ] ] | conninfo` (see [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html)).

Example: `\c MyDatabase`

Note that the `\c` and `\connect` meta-commands are **[case-sensitive](http://postgresql.nabble.com/Case-sensitive-connect-in-psql-is-perplexing-td1912216.html)**.

Answer (score 11):

Use below statement to switch to different databases residing inside
your postgreSQL RDMS

```
\c databaseName
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also connect to a database with a different ROLE as follows.

```
\connect DBNAME ROLENAME;
```

or

```
\c DBNAME ROLENAME;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can connect using

\c dbname

If you would like to see all possible commands for POSTGRESQL or SQL follow this steps :

1. rails dbconsole
   (You will be redirected to your current ENV database)
2. ?
   (For POSTGRESQL commands)

or

2. \h
   (For SQL commands)
3. Press Q to Exit

Answer (score 7):

**Listing and Switching Databases in [PostgreSQL](https://orahow.com/)**
When you need to change between databases, you’ll use the \connect command, or \c followed by the database name as shown below:

```
postgres=# \connect database_name
postgres=# \c database_name
```

**Check the database you are currently connected to.**

```
SELECT current_database();
```

[PostgreSQL List Databases](https://orahow.com/listing-databases-in-postgresql/)

```
postgres=# \l
 postgres=# \list
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to switch to a specific database on startup, try

`/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/psql vigneshdb;`

By default, Postgres runs on the port 5432. If it runs on another, make sure to pass the port in the command line.

`/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/psql -p2345 vigneshdb;`

By a simple alias, we can make it handy.

Create an alias in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`

```
function psql()
{
    db=vigneshdb
    if [ "$1" != ""]; then
            db=$1
    fi
    /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/psql -p5432 $1
}
```

Run `psql` in command line, it will switch to default database; `psql anotherdb`, it will switch to the db with the name in argument, on startup.

Answer (score 3):

```
  Connect to database:

  Method 1 : enter to db : sudo -u postgres psql

  Connect to db : \c dbname

  Method 2 : directly connect to db : sudo -u postgres psql -d my_database_name
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SET schema 'schemaName';
```

The correct translation of 'use databasename;' from mysql to postgreSQL has to consider that in postgreSQL you have also schemas. Usually your connection string has alreday defined the databasename, you have to specify the default schema.

After setting the schema name you can execute query like:

```
SELECT * from tableName;
```

without repeating the schemaName like here:

```
SELECT * from schemaName.tableName;
```

Comment: schema in postgres is NOT the same as a database.

Answer (score -16):

You can just enter `use [dbName]` to switch between databases without reentering your password.

Comment: This is not valid syntax in psql (though it is in MySQL, but that's a completely different database.