# How to DROP tables from specific database-schema in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgresql and so far I have not found a way to drop a table from specific database. To give some context:

We are doing a synchronization from Oracle to PostgreSQL of 5 tables. In postgres I have a database `SoloCopy` and the schema is the default `public`. In the Postgresql instance we have also 2 more databases `SoloSynch` and `postgres` (the default one).

What I want to do is to select `SoloCopy` database and:

```
DROP TABLE public.table1;
```

When I do the above `DROP` statement table1 is deleted only from the database that was selected when opening SQL Query. But I want to specify the database before that and to be irrelevant from where the SQL Query was open. How can I do that?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10338367) help you?

Comment: No, unfortunately nothing from this topic helps me. I need to select a specific database before running the `DROP` statements. But pgAdmin opens the Query tool for a cpecific database and it does not seem like I can switch to another with code...

Comment: - you can make cross-database queries if you want do it in pgAdmin https://fedingo.com/how-to-make-cross-database-queries-in-postgresql/ - if you want do it by code better solve its do it using different connections. (open connection and do query with this connection, and do same with another connection...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on my own. Setup can be found here:
[Psql in Task Scheduler does not run a file script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73305461/psql-in-task-scheduler-does-not-run-a-file-script/73329991#73329991)

Basically I needed to use **PSQL** and with the connection string there I connect to a specific DB, which I can drop the tables from. The details for **PGPASSWORD** and the **.bat** file I ended up creating are in the link above. Had to start everything from **CMD** and switch to **psql** from there.