# Create a database and two tables using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker-compose

This seems like a very easy thing to do but could you tell me where I am going wrong.

I want to execute some SQL files on Postgres db start up to create a database and tables.

I use docker-compose to create a Postgres version 16.2 database
I copy 3 SQL files ( named so they execute sequentially) into docker-entrypoint-initdb.d  where they are executed, this works!
I want the tables to belong in the created database, but I cannot get that working

Here are the files.

aa.sql

```
CREATE USER user1 WITH PASSWORD 'password';
CREATE DATABASE products;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE products TO user1;
```

bb.sql (runs after aa.sql):

```
CREATE TABLE brands (
    brand_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    brand_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

cc.sql (runs after bb.sql)

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    brand_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY (brand_id)
            REFERENCES products.brands (brand_id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

If I run my docker-compose I see the tables are created in the postgres database not products

If I use CREATE_TABLE databasename.tablename , no tables are created

If I use USE products;  I get

```
psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/bb.sql:1: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USE"
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: PostgreSQL does provide error messages, when something goes wrong, like for example when a table does not get created.  When you do not see any errors, you might need to use the CONNECT statement, see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-sql-connect.html

Comment: You could create the database and user with the `POSTGRES_DB` and `POSTGRES_USER` (and others) environment variables instead.

Comment: What is error due to table is not created? Is bb.sql really executed afater aa.sql - there is FK, so this can be problem.

Comment: PostgreSQL does not have `USE`, it has `search_path`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335561/use-database-name-command-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments.

I found this resolves the problem (connect to the right db first using the code below)

```
\connect products

CREATE TABLE products (
    product_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    brand_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY (brand_id)
            REFERENCES brands (brand_id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```