# How can I change database inside Shell on Google Cloud Platform using PostgreSQL (psql)?

Tags: database, postgresql, shell, google-cloud-platform, database-connection

On GCP, when you connect to Google Cloud Shell, and then connect to PostgreSQL database instance using "gcloud sql connect..." GCP connects you to postgres database.

How can I change to another database already created?

Is there any psql (or specific GCP Shell) command to change database connection?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried GCP, so I'm not sure if this works there.  But in some of my scripts I've the need to do this.

In those scripts, I use

\c DBNAME

More info: [How to switch databases in psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949876/how-to-switch-databases-in-psql)

Comment: But where should I type that?

Comment: If you're running it through psql you can put it right in your script.   Here's a gist I created that shows how to do it.  https://gist.github.com/ssargent/e315cd90ebd9ad9b915f324be71cc41e  Just add \c DBNAME; in the script and it changes the database.  In this example I connect to my main db, and then change to the two databases i created db1 and db2

Answer (score 1):

As @scottsargent answer: \c DBNAME is the solution.

You need on GCP Shell to add a semicolon `;` at the end, press ENTER and provide the user password to change database connection when psql ask for it:

```
postgres=> \c elboticario;
Password for user postgres:
psql (9.6.7, server 9.6.6)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: **************-SHA256, bits: 128, compression: off)
You are now connected to database "elboticario" as user "postgres".
elboticario=>
```