# PGAdmin4 not creating table after postgreSQL migrate

Tags: django, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am new to Django and trying to migrate my PostgreSQL query to PGAdmin4. Everything is working fine - the `makemigrations` command, the `sqlmigrate` command, and even the `migrate` command is not producing any errors. But I can't see my table in PGAdmin4 on refreshing.
My `settings.py` file's Database part is as

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'demo',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}
```

`migrate` is creating no errors as

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, travel
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying travel.0001_initial... OK
```

The user has all the privileges, my `\du` command is resulting in

```
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 Swati     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 swati     | Superuser                                                  | {}
 travel    |                                                            | {}
```

Any help shall be appreciated.

Comment: Are you connected to the demo database?

Comment: @schillingt I'm very new to Django and Postgresql. Can you tell me the procedure to verify my connection?

Comment: No problem. Here's a SO answer that covers that for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949885/1637351

Comment: @schillingt from my psql shell, I connected with my database (which was successful), and then ```python manage.py migrate```, but I still could not see my tables in the PGAdmin4